# Blurry font when enlarged at high resolution in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I have Windows 7 on a monitor running at 1680x1050 resolution.  The problem is that font appears blurred when increased to 150% size! This does not happen when I am running Ubuntu (from the second partition).

How can I set Windows 7 to show me a CLEAR but also LARGE font without loss in quality? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just changed monitors or resolutions or especially monitor orientation (or just moved to Win7) you should try adjusting your ClearType settings.  The easiest thing to do is just search 'ClearType' on the Start Menu, select the result for 'Adjust ClearType text', and go through the wizard steps.  This will adjust the smoothing on the fonts and should result in sharper text.